# OneHotEncoder Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to encode a data table with multiple columns to a given set of categories

```
ohe1 = OneHotEncoder(categories = [list_names_data_rest.values],dtype = 'int8')
data_rest1 = ohe1.fit_transform(data_rest.values).toarray()
```

Here, `list_names_data_rest.values` is an array of shape (664,). I have 664 unique features and i am trying to encode `data_rest` which is (5050,6). After encoding, I am expecting a shape (5050,664)

I am one hot encoding to a pre-defined features set because, I am downloading data sets in chunks (due to ram limitations) and I would like the input shape to my neural network to be consistent

If i use `pd.get_dummies`, depending on my data set, I could get different categories and different input shape for my NN

`ohe1.fit_transform` does require a shape (n_values, n_features) but, I do not know how to handle this.

Comment: Hey @Varoon, your original data has 6 features. How do you want this to be encoded? Say for instance "a" and "b" are in your categories list, how do you encode

row1 =  ["a","a","a","a","a","a"] and

row2 =  ["a","a","a","b","b","b"] ?

Answer (score 0):

`HashingVectorizer` maybe a good solution for your case.It is independent from number of input features , just set initial size big enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use `pd.get_dummies` there is an option to iteratively include your encodings for every batch.

For your first batch:

```
ohe = pd.get_dummies(data_rest, columns=['label_col'])
```

For every subsequent batch:

```
for b in batches:
    batch_ohe = pd.get_dummies(b, columns=['label_col'])
    ohe = pd.concat([ohe, batch_ohe], axis=0)

ohe = ohe.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this will change my input dimension to the neural network. The idea of using batches is to retain the network architecture and learn from the new data

Comment: You could encode your entire dataset first and then start batch-wise training?

Comment: I do have memory issues which is why i am encoding them in batches

Comment: I meant you could encode your dataset in batches first and then when you are done with the batch-wise encoding, you can start training. If you start training on partially encoded labels then for the new labels the model would not know how to change the label encodings it has seen in previous batches. You need to keep your architecture consistent so that you NN knows how many labels it is going to encounter and calculate the proabability distribution accordingly based on the total (not partial) number of output nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I once tired to load the entire data set and applied get_dummies but i had memory issues. do you think encoding in batches will fix it? I still will have all the training set in my RAM before training the model.

Comment: I think encoding in batches should work. Once you are done with encoding, save your dataset (maybe as csv or in binary format using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)). And then read it in batches again while training.